# Vue.js option component for select

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I'm trying to create this component:

```
<template>
  <option v-for="(text, value) in options" :value="value">
    {{ text }}
  </option>
</template>
```

But I get this error message:

> template syntax error Cannot use v-for on stateful component root element because it renders multiple elements

How could I create this kind of component?
I'm using vue 2.0.5

Here are some relevant docs: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#DOM-Template-Parsing-Caveats

Comment: How does your options variable looks, can you add this in the question and which version of Vue you are using?

Comment: I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5mdgwt43/1/), It seems working fine in this, whats the issue here?

Comment: Now try to convert option into a component

Comment: You should have a single root element for components, `v-for` renders multiple elements obviously. Wrap it in a parent element.

Comment: Sure, but a option tag CAN'T be wrapped, is there any workaround for this? Maybe some way to unwrap after rendering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that inside a component, you need one top level element so you're going to need to wrap that in a select and have the entire select box as your component. You will then need to pass any options as props, so:

Template:

```
<template id="my-select">
  <select>
    <option v-for="(text, value) in options" :value="value">
      {{ text }}
    </option>
  </select>
</template>
```

Component:

```
Vue.component('my-select', {
  props: ['options'],
  template: "#my-select"
});
```

View Model:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    options: {
      "1": "foo",
      "2": "bar",
      "3": "baz"
    }
  }
});
```

Now in your root page, just pass the options as a prop:

```
<my-select :options="options"></my-select>
```

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zL6woLa2/

Comment: Since that's the only way, is this the right way to make v-model work again? https://jsfiddle.net/neves/zL6woLa2/1/ and why slot doesn't work inside select?

Comment: I think that looks pretty good. Personally, I try to keep everything associated with the component inside the component, so I would probably keep `v-model` in the component and $emit to a `bus` on an event. I'm not sure why the `slot` doesn't work here, but it's probably easier to just pass the default option as a prop and show it if a value was passed. Here's my updated version of your fiddle, but as I say, this is how I would do it, so stick with your solution if you prefer: https://jsfiddle.net/08qr3rL9/